# MS Excel - Combine tables with only some matching data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, database

I have 2 sets of data that I want to combine into one table. I have tried to use Power Query but I don't think it can quite do what I am after and was wondering if there is another way.

It might be easier to explain what I am trying to achieve with an example.
[Excel table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zufMX.jpg)

Looking at the example you can see that there is two sets of data for a number of schools. I have some data for both schools and only one set of data for others.

Looking at the example you can see that **School a** has data from both the **data 1** and **data 2** tables, however **school f** only has data from the **data 2** table.

Is there a way to end up with what I have in the far right example on sheet 3. If a school has both sets of data, the data is combined. If a school does not appear in both sets it will add the school to the bottom of the list so all data is retained, not just the matching data.

Comment: power query is your best bet for something like this, you will want data->get data->other sources->table. Do this for both tables. then data->get->data-merge, haven't got time to write as answer, give it a go tho, if you get there post it as an answer, welcome to SU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

- append one table to the other
- Group By School
- Extract Data1 and Data2 into custom columns

```
let
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblSchool1"]}[Content],
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblSchool2"]}[Content],
    combTbl = Table.Combine({Source1,Source2}),

    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(combTbl, {"School"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [School=text, Data 1=nullable text, Data 2=nullable text]}}),

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Data 1", each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],"Data 1")){0}
        otherwise null),

    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Data 2", each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],"Data 2")){0}
        otherwise null),
    
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Grouped"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that answer Ron. I'm not sure I follow exactly how to extract the data into custom columns with the code you appended, but I will try and figure it out.

Comment: @Rory The code I provided will create the custom columns.  After pasting it into the Advanced Editor, all you should need to do is edit the table names in lines 2 and 3 to match the actual table names of your two data tables.

Comment: Hi Ron, so I click in a cell for the table, choose From Table > Close and Load to > Only create connection, for each table. Do I need to then merge the tables with a Combine Query or can I load in the code you supplied into an advanced editor without having to do a query? Sorry I am pretty new to doing this stuff in Excel

Comment: After ensuring you know the table names for your two Source tables, I suggest `Data`=> `Get Data` => `From other source` => `Blank Query` and then paste the code into the AE.  Then edit lines 2 and 3 for the correct table names.  You can decide about connection vs where you want the results when you are finished and do `Close and Load to`; or you can merely `Close and Load` to write the results to a new worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Ron Rosenfeld I got that example to work once I figured out where the Advanced Editor was. The example above example was a simplified version of the data set that I am actually trying to work on. Given that I didn't know if Excel could do what I wanted I figured I would try and figure out the most basic example of what I wanted to achieve and then expand from there to the full table once I understood the basics.
I have added a part 2 to my original post explaining in more detail about what I am actually trying to achieve. Thanks again for your help and patience.

Comment: @Rory Maybe this forum works differently than what you are used to. If you have a question about supplied code, post a comment to the one who supplied the code.  And don't expand your question to the "real" question.. Rather, ask another question with your new attempts and problems. The code is called `M-Code` and you can learn a lot about what is going on by examining the applied steps window in the PQ editor; and also by examining the online documentation from Microsoft, and numerous blogs.  Line 6 uses the `Table.Group` function, and is grouping the table by the School..

Comment: Thanks for the information @ron. I will have a look into M-Code and try and learn a bit more about how it works. Thanks again for your help.