# MS Excel - Combine tables using M code

Tags: microsoft-excel, code

I have a file with 3 different tables on individual sheets. The tables all have a different number of columns and rows but they all have 1 column in common.
I previously asked a simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish in this link here
[MS Excel - Combine tables with only some matching data](https://superuser.com/questions/1615980/ms-excel-combine-tables-with-only-some-matching-data)

Another user, Ron gave me some code that solved the basic premise of what I want to do so I took that code and I have tried editing it.
In my first attempt I have tried to add the tables in the first and second sheets together. It has almost worked but not quite.

The first 3 steps seem to work just fine, and I think the 4th step (Grouped Rows) has worked but I’m not certain.
The main problem seems to be that the step Added Custom and Added Custom 1 put in the first 2 columns I need but when I get to Added Custom 2, instead of ADDING another column to the right it REPLACES the previously added column. The next few steps which I want to add in the remaining columns, it still only replaces the last column with the new one so that there is only ever 2 custom columns.
Here is my 3 tables

[image: Excel tables]

Here is the code after I edited:

```
let
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=”WACEAchievement”]}[Content],
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=”MedianATAR”]}[Content],
    combTbl = Table.Combine({Source1,Source2}),

    #”Grouped Rows” = Table.Group(combTbl, {“School”}, {{“Grouped”, each _, type table [School=text, Number of eligible year 12 students=nullable text, percent students who achieved the WACE=nullable text, Number of students with an ATAR=nullable text, percent of students with an ATAR=nullable text, Median ATAR=nullable text]}}),

    #”Added Custom” = Table.AddColumn(#”Grouped Rows”, “Number of eligible year 12 students”, each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],”Number of eligible year 12 students”)){0}
        otherwise null),

    #”Added Custom1” = Table.AddColumn(#”Added Custom”, “percent students who achieved the WACE”, each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],”percent students who achieved the WACE”)){0}
        otherwise null),
        
    #”Added Custom2” = Table.AddColumn(#”Added Custom”, “Number of students with an ATAR”, each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],”Number of students with an ATAR”)){0}
        otherwise null),
        
    #”Added Custom3” = Table.AddColumn(#”Added Custom”, “percent of students with an ATAR”, each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],”percent of students with an ATAR”)){0}
        otherwise null),
        
    #”Added Custom4” = Table.AddColumn(#”Added Custom”, “Median ATAR”, each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],”Median ATAR”)){0}
        otherwise null),        
    
    #”Removed Columns” = Table.RemoveColumns(#”Added Custom1”,{“Grouped”})
in
    #”Removed Columns”
```

Here is some examples of what is happening with the different steps.
[image: Step1]
[image: Step2]
[image]

Here is a progress shot that I am getting stuck on
[image: Duplicate entires]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find this much easier if you don't try to edit the code and instead use the UI to get your results. For example, if I start here:

[image]

I create a query on each table in turn, using Data>From Table/Range. I click "Close & Load To" in the Power Query Editor and configure it like this:

[image]

i.e. "Only Create Connection"

Now I have three queries:

[image]

Next, I use Data>Get Data>Combine Queries>Merge and configure it like this:

[image]

Note that it's very important that you choose "Full Outer" in the Join Kind drop-down.

After clicking OK, I have this:

[image]

I click the double-arrow at the top of the column "Table2" and do this:

[image]

i.e. I deselect "Use original column name as prefix" and leave all of the columns selected.

Now I have this:

[image]

Note that I now have two "School" columns - "School", which contains the list of schools present in Table1, and "School.1", which contains the list of schools present in Table2.

We need to merge these columns before adding the data from Table3 to the query.

To help make this clearer, I first rename each of those school columns by double-clicking the header and typing a new name:

[image]

Next, I use Add Column>Custom Column and configure it like this:

[image]

Note that M is case-sensitive and the if-then-else must be in lower case.

Now I have my new column:

[image]

I right click Table1Schools and Table2Schools and select "Remove", then drag the new "School" column to the left of the remainder of the columns (not strictly necessary, but helps to stay organized). Now I have a School column with a school ID in each row. I also have the data from Table1 and Table2:

[image]

Next, I want to Merge Table3 with this query. So, in the Power Query Editor, I use Merge Queries on the Home tab. I configure it like this:

[image]

Note that the first table is actually "Merge1", which was the end-result of merging Table1 and Table2.

After expanding the Table3 column in the same way as above, I have this:

[image]

So, I have one row where School is null. I need to repeat the new column process I followed above. So, I rename the columns:

[image]

Then create a new column with a formula similar to above:

[image]

After removing Merge1School and Table3School, then moving the new column to the far-left, I have the required result:

[image]

Again, I recommend using the UI where possible as it will save you lots of time. For info, the resulting query is this:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Table1, {"School"}, Table2, {"School"}, "Table2", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table2", {"School", "Data 2"}, {"School.1", "Data 2"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Table2",{{"School", "Table1Schools"}, {"School.1", "Table2Schools"}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "School", each if [Table1Schools] is null then [Table2Schools] else [Table1Schools]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Table1Schools", "Table2Schools"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"School", "Data 1", "Data 2"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Reordered Columns", {"School"}, Table3, {"School"}, "Table3", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded Table3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table3", {"School", "Data 3"}, {"School.1", "Data 3"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Table3",{{"School", "Merge1School"}, {"School.1", "Table3School"}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "School", each if [Merge1School] is null then [Table3School] else [Merge1School]),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Merge1School", "Table3School"}),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{"School", "Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns1"
```

Of course, the column renaming steps are not strictly necessary in this query (since they are removed shortly after renaming them) and you could wait until the last step to remove columns you don't want.

Comment: Thanks very much for providing such a detailed answer! That is really helpful. I will give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: No problem. You may find that if you have schools in one table but not the other, there will be an additional step needed to ensure you have appropriate row headers on each row. Let me know if that's an issue and I will edit my post to include how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, @FlexYourData that is actually the case that some schools only appear in some tables but not others. So if I was to do a regular merge of 2 of the tables then I can only get either just the rows that match, missing out on the ones that don't match, or if I include all of the rows, then I get a double up of school rows.

Comment: I've rewritten the answer to explain how you would deal with schools in some tables and not others.

Comment: I know it has been a while since you answered @flexYourData but I finally got back to figuring this out and I worked through your answer. It was really helpful being able to see all of the steps and how it progresses so thanks again for all of the detail and screen shots.

Comment: Thanks for saying so. I genuinely think Excel is a useful tool and I like to share what I've learned over the years. If it helps in only a small way, then it was worth the time.

Comment: Hi @flexYourData I have been trying to figure out what i am doing wrong. Every time I work through the steps I can combine all of the tables and make the custom column but the rows that should match up because they have the same School name are not combining into a single row. Essentially it is just adding another row underneath. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: I have added in a picture at the bottom of my question that might demonstrate the issue I am having

Comment: Please add the code from your Home>Advanced Editor. You should also ensure that you have no trailing spaces after the end of each school name. You can do this in each query by right-clicking the school name column and selecting Transform>Trim

Comment: Thanks for the tip @flexYourData! I must have had a trailing space in one of the headers. I made sure they were all fixed and it has worked perfectly. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You were very close in doing your code editing:

You wrote, for example:

```
 #”Added Custom2” = Table.AddColumn(#”Added Custom”, “Number of students with an ATAR”, each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],”Number of students with an ATAR”)){0}
        otherwise null),
```

But note that in the first line, you are adding the column to the `#"Added Custom"` table.    But at each step, you need to add the custom column to the Table generated by the **preceding step**, in order to preserve the preceding table.

So `#"Added Custom2"` should be added to the `#"Added Custom1"` table; and so forth.

So, instead: *(and also note you can have all three tables in your `Table.Combine`)*

```
let
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="WACE"]}[Content],
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ATAR"]}[Content],
    Source3 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CERTII"]}[Content],
    combTbl = Table.Combine({Source1,Source2,Source3}),

    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(combTbl, {"School"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [School=text, Data 1=nullable text, Data 2=nullable text]}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"School", Order.Ascending}}),

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Number of eligible year 12 students", each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],"Number of eligible year 12 students")){0}
        otherwise null),

    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "percent students who achieved the WACE", each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],"percent students who achieved the WACE")){0}
        otherwise null),

    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Number of students with an ATAR", each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],"Number of students with an ATAR")){0}
        otherwise null),

    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "percent of students with an ATAR", each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],"percent of students with an ATAR")){0}
        otherwise null),

    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Median ATAR", each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],"Median ATAR")){0}
        otherwise null),

    #"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Number completed Cert II or higher but less than four ATAR courses", each try
            List.RemoveNulls(Table.Column([Grouped],"Number completed Cert II or higher but less than four ATAR Courses")){0}
        otherwise null),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom5",{"Grouped"})

in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

***Note** Given the nature of your data, after you combine the three tables, you could do the rest from the UI by selecting:*

- GroupBy `School`
- Select `Advanced`
- Then add an aggregation for each column with a `Sum` (or other arithmetic) operation.

  - Since there is only a single entry per school/column combination, various arithmetic operations (but not count), will return the appropriate value.

**aggregation example**

[image]

- Note that, since I am lazy, I named the new columns alphabetically.
- I then added a few lines manually in the Advanced Editor in order to name them according to their original names.
- You could, of course, eliminate that by entering the same name for `New Column Name` as the column being aggregated.
- I have no idea whether this method or the previous one would be more efficient.

```
let
    Source1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="WACE"]}[Content],
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ATAR"]}[Content],
    Source3 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CERTII"]}[Content],

combTbl = Table.Combine({Source1,Source2,Source3}),

    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(combTbl, {"School"}, {
        {"a", each List.Sum([Number of eligible year 12 students]), type nullable number}, 
        {"b", each List.Sum([percent students who achieved the WACE]), type nullable number}, 
        {"c", each List.Sum([Number of students with an ATAR]), type nullable number}, 
        {"d", each List.Sum([percent of students with an ATAR]), type nullable number}, 
        {"e", each List.Sum([Median ATAR]), type nullable number}, 
        {"f", each List.Sum([Number completed Cert II or higher but less than four ATAR Courses]), type nullable number}
            }),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"School", Order.Ascending}}),

//rename the aggregated columns
newColNames = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(combTbl),1),
curColNames = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Grouped Rows"),1),
renameList = List.Zip({curColNames,newColNames}),
reName = Table.RenameColumns(#"Sorted Rows",renameList)

in
    reName
```